# How do I connect Borderlands 2 Mac and PC through LAN?

Tags: pc, borderlands-2, macos

Trying to get Mac and PC Borderlands 2 to play together over LAN

Game Ranger's Mac client doesn't have Borderlands 2. Hamachi did not work. Also tried Tunngle, to no avail.

We both have the same version of BL2 with all DLCs. Is there any way for us to play together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows steam Borderlands 2 can only cross platform play with the Steam Borderlands 2 for Mac (and vice versa). As you have mentioned Game Ranger, it sounds like you are not using the Steam version of Borderlands 2 for Mac.

> Mac App players are able to play with other Mac App players ONLY.  Mac App players will NOT be able to play with Mac or PC players using Steam.

[source](http://support.aspyr.com/entries/22353786-Borderlands-2-FAQ-)

Comment: This is a misleading answer. That FAQ answer is only for the version of Borderlands distributed through the Mac App Store. If you have the Steam version on the Mac you can play with Windows users. From the same source: Q: Will Mac players be able to play with PC players in multiplayer co-op? A:  Yes!

Comment: ... the answer says steam mac/windows games can cross platform play, and Mac Appstore can only play with Mac Appstore... which is the case...